# XAMMP. Object not found! Error 404 localhost

Tags: php, laravel, apache, xampp

I just installed XAMPP on my Mac. After configured everything and tried to run myProject on localhost 8080 the following error showed up on the web.

localhost:8080/myProject

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost

`Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.9 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0`

Here's the configurations for XAMPP

[image: XAMPP]

[image: XAMPP-port]

Here's the files under htdocs

[image: htdocs]

`Document root`:

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">


Include etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
Include "/opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"
```

`httpd.xampp.conf`

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
   AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 >/error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

`apache2/conf/httpd.conf`

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

`etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" >common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" >common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost laravel.local:80>
  DocumentRoot " 
/Users/phamminh/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/myProject/public"
  ServerAdmin laravel.local
  <Directory " 
/Users/phamminh/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/myProject">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```